# Unitialized constant User:Bookings when trying to add data into a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a User table and a Booking Table that is linked by a create_join_table what holds the user id and booking ids. When a user books a room, i need the id of both the user and new booking to go into that. I am getting the error above and im not sure why.

I have looked online and saw something similar, their class names were plural however I don't think I have that.

booking.rb

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  enum room_type: ["Basic Room", "Deluxe Room", "Super-Deluxe Room", "Piton Suite"]
  has_many :join_tables
  has_many :users, through: :join_tables
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_secure_password
  validates :email, format: {with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP}, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_many :join_tables
  has_many :bookings, through: :join_tables
end
```

join_table.rb

```
class JoinTable < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :bookings
end
```

bookings_controller.rb

```
def create
  @booking = Booking.create(booking_params)
  current_user.bookings << @booking           ##Where the error happens
```

db/schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_12_13_181019) do

  create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "room_type"
    t.date "check_in"
    t.date "check_out"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "join_tables", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.integer "users_id"
     t.integer "bookings_id"
     t.datetime "created_at", null: false
     t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
     t.index ["bookings_id"], name: "index_join_tables_on_bookings_id"
     t.index ["users_id"], name: "index_join_tables_on_users_id"
 end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just tried to reproduce your problem and I have a similar exception

```
irb(main):003:0> User.first.bookings
NameError (uninitialized constant User::Bookings)
```

but, when I change

```rb
belongs_to :users
belongs_to :bookings
```

to

```rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :booking
```

in `app/models/join_table.rb` everything works as expected.

This is how I created the `JoinTable` model

```
$ rails generate model JoinTable
```

```rb
class CreateJoinTables < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :join_tables do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :booking

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see in the [`belongs_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) docs, it is used in the singular form most of the time.

Comment: I knew I was missing something! Thanks, had a look at the join table and it has the values there.Thanks!